CGImage.crop(to:) returns a weird crop on MacOS
I was facing a weird behavior while using the method CGImage.crop(to:).
My goal is cropping a user face using the apple vision-framework to train AI-based models on it, but while running the vision on the utkface dataset I got a completely weird crop, see examples above.
Here is the relevant piece of code:

        let image = NSImage(byReferencingFile: imagePath)!
        let cgImage = image.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil)!
        
        let visionRequest = VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest()

        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, orientation: .up, options: [:])
        do {
            try await handler.perform([visionRequest])
        } catch {
            print("Failed ... \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        let observations = visionRequest.results?
            .filter {
                $0.confidence >= request.faceCaptureThreshold &&
                ($0.boundingBox.size.width >= 0.1 || $0.boundingBox.size.height >= 0.1)
            } ?? []

        for (index, observation) in observations.enumerated() {
            let normalizedBoundingBox = observation.boundingBox
            let boundingBox = VNImageRectForNormalizedRect(normalizedBoundingBox, cgImage.width, cgImage.height)
            let croppedImage = cgImage.cropping(to: boundingBox)!
            // Redacted: store croppedImage on Disk
        }

While debugging this, I was able to discovery that everything is going fine, until the function crop(to:) be called, what's weird, because when I draw a rect above the original image using CoreImage-related functions the rect is on the right place, but the crop is completely different.
I was able to work around this, recreating the image using CoreImage, something like:
            let croppedImage = DrawImageInCGContext(size: boundingBox.size) { (context) -> () in
                context.draw(cgImage, in: .init(origin: .init(x: -boundingBox.minX, y: -boundingBox.minY), size: CGSize(width: cgImage.width, height: cgImage.height)), byTiling: true)
            }

But I didn't understand what I was doing wrong when using the CGImage.crop(to:), or if it's a bug on Apple-side.
Any ideas?




coordinate system starts in the bottom left? IDK, looks like it.

Yes; Mac's coordinate system starts in the lower left and increasing y values go up. iOS starts in the upper left and increasing y values go down. You often need to flip views (look for an isFlipped property), or apply affine transforms to line up the coordinates. I haven't studied this code to figure out exactly which way you need to fix it, but that's what you're looking for.

You guys are right, debugging it again, I discovered that vision is returning a "flipped" coordinate system and CGImage.crop(to:) wants a non-flipped coordinates.
So I need to recreate the rect moving the y-origin to the right coordinate-space, something like CGFloat(cgImage.height) - boundingBox.maxY

What's happening here is that macOS uses a different coordinate system starting from bottom left corner instead of up left corner, like iOS. But CGImage.crop(to:) expects an up left corner based rect to crop the image, so a translation is needed to crop it correctly.
A small change is enough to fix that:
            let normalizedBoundingBox = observation.boundingBox
            let boundingBox = VNImageRectForNormalizedRect(normalizedBoundingBox, cgImage.width, cgImage.height)
            
            let flippedY = CGFloat(cgImage.height) - boundingBox.maxY
            
            let macOSBoundingBox = CGRect(
                origin: .init(x: boundingBox.minX, y: flippedY),
                size: boundingBox.size
            )

